# Can 'singer' be used as an uncount noun?

Tags: nouns, determiners, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> Singer Mizuki Nana and her sister took viewers by surprise with
>   their voracious eating of roasted duck.

Macmillan learner's dictionary says 'singer' is a count noun. Might I trouble you to tell me why 'singer' is used as an uncount noun? There can't be seen any determiner before 'singer'.

Comment: Policeman Ronald Jones arrested the burglar, swimmer Aisha Patel crossed the river, soldier James Akenoye was awarded a medal. All count nouns, all used without an article in news reports. Very common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Singer" is used count noun.

But here it is being used as an attributive noun, so the question of whether a determiner is needed is answered by the noun it is describing: "Mizuki Nana".

Since Mizuki Nana is a proper name, it has no determiner. Whether "singer" is count or non-count doesn't matter.

Note that it would be possible to re-arrange the apposition, in which case a determiner would be used

> Mizuki Nana, the singer, and her sister...